# Index was outside the bounds of the array Error in my Homework

Tags: c#

idk what to do... xD

```
string[] textLines = new string[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    textLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Computername\Downloads\Filename.txt");
}
Console.WriteLine("Random Text");
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(textLines[i]);
}
```

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: The number of elements of `textLines[]` will be equal to the number of lines in your file, so if it has less than 20 lines your loop will go off the end. (Also note that you don't need a loop to read `textLines` - just call `ReadAllLines()` once.)

Comment: Why don't you just use `ReadAllText()` to read it's all text as a string?